# <ion-content> goes behind <ion-header> in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
<ion-header> 
  <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>Physics</ion-title> 
 </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding has-header contentTop="200px"> 
  <ion-list class="chapter-list"> 
      <button ion-item no-padding *ngFor="let chapterList of chapterLists" (click)="chapterListItemClk(event)" no-border> {{ chapterList.video_name }} <img src="{{chapterList.video_icon}}" item-left alt=""> </button> 
  </ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

This is my code in which `<ion-content>` is hiding behind `<ion-header>`.
My ionic version is 3.19.1.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this.
I have tried has-header as well.

Comment: What's your class chapter-list?

Comment: `.chapter-list{
  img{
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 11px 0px 0px !important;
  }
  ion-label.label.label-md {
    white-space: unset;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 1.5rem
  }
  button{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  }
  .item-inner{
    border: none !important;
  }
}`

This is styling which i gave to list.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<ion-grid></ion-grid>` inside ion-content tag

```
<ion-header> 
  <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>Physics</ion-title> 
 </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding has-header contentTop="200px">
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-list class="chapter-list"> 
      <button ion-item no-padding *ngFor="let chapterList of chapterLists" (click)="chapterListItemClk(event)" no-border> {{ chapterList.video_name }} <img src="{{chapterList.video_icon}}" item-left alt=""> </button> 
  </ion-list> 
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```